# Pass ruby array in js file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have an array obtained from a query in my controller

```
@users
```

I'm able to show the result on my view, but I need to pass it into a ".js" file.

I have found that I need to use json so I have written this on my ".js"

```
var dataset = {
  ex1: [<%= raw @users.to_json %>],
  ex2: [100, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200]
};
```

but it doesn't work. Normally my view process static data on load, now I need to dinamically change these.

I have also added

```
//= require json
```

but no luck.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your file has to be named: **myfile.js.erb**

This means your file content will be first evaluated for ruby code THEN for javascript code.
This is why your views are named myview.html.erb or myview.html.haml etc...
The same way goes for javascript and css assets: their names end with **.js.coffee** or **.css.scss** in order for them to be evaluated for CoffeScript or SCSS then Javascript or CSS.

Comment: I have renamed the ".js" into ".js.erb" but it continues to give me error on the file. Where I need to put this file now? I have it on "assets/javascript"

Comment: Place it under **views/your_controller_views_folder/controller_method_name.js.erb** and in your controller method: respond_to {|format| format.js } If you don't understand all I just said, then maybe it's time to go check the guides http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Answer (score 1):

Your javascript file has to have an erb extension at the end: `file.js.erb` for you to be able to interpolate ruby code.